# How to prove that the class of regular languages is closed under a homomorphism.

Tags: proof-writing, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

**I have created two homomorphisms**

*Homomorphism with the same language:*

In this task, I consider the homomorphism $f: \Sigma \rightarrow \Sigma^*$ for the alphabet $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$. In that case:

$f(0) = 1$

$f(1) = 0$

Given the string $s = 01001$, the corresponding $f(s)$ becomes $f(s) = 10110$.

*Homomorphism without the same language:*

$f: \sum \rightarrow \Gamma^*$ that uses different alphabets: $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$ and $\Gamma = \{a, b\}$. In that case:

$f(0) = a$

$f(1) = b$

Given the string $s = 01001$, the corresponding $f(s)$ becomes $f(s) = abaab$.

**Question:**
How do I prove that the class of regular languages is closed under a homomorphism based on my constructions above?

I got the following hint, but still can't figure it out:
You can think of a DFA $M$ that recognizes $A$ and a homomorphism $f$, construct a second finite automata, $M_0$ that recognizes $B$, where $B = f(A)$. Then, is the new finite automata, $M_0$ , a DFA? if yes, you have proven that $B$ is accepted by $M_0$. Recall, that an operation is regular if it is defined between one or more regular languages, and the result of the operation is also a regular language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard proof to show that the class of regular languages is closed under homomorphisms is to use [Kleene's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) on regular languages. Indeed, it is easy to construct a regular expression for $f(R)$, given a regular expression for $R$.

If you insist to use automata, you can start with a deterministic automaton $\cal A$ for $R$ and replace every transition $p \xrightarrow{a} q$ by a transition $p \xrightarrow{f(a)} q$. This gives you an *extended automaton* (the transitions are now labelled by words) which can be converted to a NFA by adding new states and by "spelling" $f(a)$. Thus, for instance if $f(a) = 010$, you would obtain a transition $p \xrightarrow{0} p_1 \xrightarrow{1} p_2 \xrightarrow{0} q$, where $p_0$ and $p_1$ are new states.

Comment: Once again, what if $f(a)=\epsilon$?

Comment: If $f(a) = \epsilon$, just replace $p \xrightarrow{a} q$ by $p \xrightarrow{\epsilon} q$. You will get a NFA with $\epsilon$-transitions.